# использование методов библиотеки numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

снова вопрос по numpy. хочу возвести все элементы четных столбцов, и так же все элементы четных строк в квадрат. пытался через `np.where`, через `np.square`, но ничего не вышло. додумался только до примитивного двойного `for`. Как все таки решить эту задачу используя именно методы `numpy`?

```
def sqr_even_colum(matrix):
    for i in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        for j in range(matrix.shape[0]):
            if j % 2 != 0:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] ** 2
    return matrix

def sqr_even_str(matrix):
    for i in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            matrix[i] = matrix[i] ** 2
    return matrix
```

предложили вот такое решение

```
def sqr_even_colum(matrix):
    matrix[:,1::2] = matrix[:,1::2] ** 2
    return matrix

def sqr_even_str(matrix):
    matrix[1::2,:] = matrix[1::2,:] ** 2
    return matrix
```

тогда сразу вопрос, а если захочу только четные элементы возводить в квадрат, а не все?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь Numpy индексированием:

Пример данных:

```
In [221]: a = np.arange(1, 26).reshape(5,5)

In [222]: a
Out[222]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

решение:

```
a2 = a**2
a[:, 1::2] = a2[:, 1::2]
a[1::2, :] = a2[1::2, :]
```

результат:

```
In [231]: a
Out[231]:
array([[  1,   4,   3,  16,   5],
       [ 36,  49,  64,  81, 100],
       [ 11, 144,  13, 196,  15],
       [256, 289, 324, 361, 400],
       [ 21, 484,  23, 576,  25]])
```

Comment: да, воспользовался вашей идеей - спасибо. а как, например, возводить в квадрат только четные элементы, а не полностью четную строку или четный столбец?